# Featured image not showing on page

Tags: wp-query, post-thumbnails

I am new to creating a theme and wonder if anyone can help?

I am trying to display all the featured images from posts under a specific category (id=5) on my index page and it's not working using the following code:

```
<?php 
$myblogPosts = new WP_Query('cat=5'); // Cat 5 is the blog category.
if ($myblogPosts->have_posts()) :
while ($myblogPosts->have_posts()) : $myblogPosts->the_post();
?>
<div class="hero_img"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div> <!--Post image-->
<?php endwhile; 
else : ?>
<p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Can anyone see why it's not working? All I get is the "Sorry, no posts" displayed where the image should be.

BTW, I got the cat id from this URL (http://localhost:8888/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?action=edit&taxonomy=category&tag_ID=5&post_type=blog)

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: This may seem like a silly question, but do you actually have any post in category 5? for example if you change it to `'cat=1'` which by default is the `Undefined` category do you get anything back?

Comment: Hi Aron, hmm, this is strange. The post comes up when I change it to 'cat=1' but it is definitely under 'cat=5' too as selecting the count in the category takes me to the post that I wanted to display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the url you supplied it looks like you are using a custom post type of **blog**. The most likely reasons you are not seeing the post you want to display is that by default `WP_Query` is only set to display posts - see WordPress Codex on [WP_Query Post & Page Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters) for more info.

So for your WP_Query to return the post you are after you will need to replace line 2:

```
$myblogPosts = new WP_Query('cat=5'); // Cat 5 is the blog category.
```

With something more like this:

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'blog', 'cat'=> 5); // Cat 5 is the blog category.
$myblogPosts = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: That is absolutely brilliant! Thank you so much and sorry for my total noobness!

Comment: ah you're welcome @Nibbers and don't worry I have been working with WP for ages now but still get caught out by things like this lol